# Subview is not using full view of container

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, subviews

So, I am using a UIView as a container for a subview that will hold Google Maps inside of it. After implementing it though there is still some of the containers that can be seen due to the fact that the subview is not using the full container like it should be. Did I do something wrong? Am I missing some code?
 This is what it currently looks like... https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT1TK.jpg

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, 
CLLocationManagerDelegate, LocateOnTheMap, 
GMSAutocompleteFetcherDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {



func didAutocomplete(with predictions: [GMSAutocompletePrediction]) {
for prediction in predictions {

    if let prediction = prediction as GMSAutocompletePrediction?{
        self.resultsArray.append(prediction.attributedFullText.string)
    }
}
self.searchResultController.reloadDataWithArray(self.resultsArray)
print(resultsArray)
 }

 func didFailAutocompleteWithError(_ error: Error) {

 }


@IBOutlet weak var MapViewContainer: UIView!

var googleMapsView: GMSMapView!
var searchResultController: SearchResultsController!
var resultsArray = [String]()
var gmsFetcher: GMSAutocompleteFetcher!

 @IBAction func searchWithAddress(_ sender: AnyObject) {
 let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultController)
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
self.present(searchController, animated:true, completion: nil)


 }


 let locationDelegate = LocationDelegate()
 var latestLocation: CLLocation? = nil
 var yourLocationBearing: CGFloat { return 
 latestLocation?.bearingToLocationRadian(self.yourLocation) ?? 0 }
 var yourLocation: CLLocation {
get { return UserDefaults.standard.currentLocation }
set { UserDefaults.standard.currentLocation = newValue }
}

//Location Manager Variable

let manager = CLLocationManager()

 //viewDidLoad

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

//Map Options

self.googleMapsView = GMSMapView(frame: self.MapViewContainer.bounds)
self.googleMapsView.clipsToBounds = true
self.MapViewContainer.addSubview(self.googleMapsView)

searchResultController = SearchResultsController()
searchResultController.delegate = self
gmsFetcher = GMSAutocompleteFetcher()
gmsFetcher.delegate = self

googleMapsView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
googleMapsView.mapType = .normal
googleMapsView.settings.compassButton = true
googleMapsView.settings.myLocationButton = true
googleMapsView.settings.zoomGestures = true

}

 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

 let location = locations.last

 let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude:(location?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom:14)
googleMapsView.animate(to: camera)

//Finally stop updating location otherwise it will come again and again in this delegate
self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}

func locateWithLongitude(_ lon: Double, andLatitude lat: Double, andTitle title: String) {

 DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in

    let position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: lon, zoom: 10)
    self.googleMapsView.camera = camera

    marker.title = "Address : \(title)"
    marker.map = self.googleMapsView


}

}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {


self.resultsArray.removeAll()
gmsFetcher?.sourceTextHasChanged(searchText)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
}
```

Comment: Try adding to the subview THEN setting the frame

Comment: add your code as code please

Comment: @ReinierMelian I just did sorry about that...

Comment: replace this line `self.googleMapsView = GMSMapsView(frame: self.MapViewContainer.frame)` by this `self.googleMapsView = GMSMapsView(frame: self.MapViewContainer.bounds)`

Comment: @ReinierMelian Sadly it did not help...

Comment: can you post an image of what you have and what you need?

Comment: @ReinierMelian well the image that I sent earlier is the same as in how it looks but the code is... `self.googleMapsView = GMSMapView(frame: self.MapViewContainer.bounds)
        self.googleMapsView.clipsToBounds = true
        self.MapViewContainer.addSubview(self.googleMapsView)`

Comment: add `self.MapViewContainer.layer.borderWidth = 1` and `self.MapViewContainer.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor` and post the result image @WhatTheHeckTech

Comment: @ReinierMelian This is the results https://imgur.com/a/VseuG

Comment: @ReinierMelian I just added all the code in the controller besides the code that you had asked me to add of course

Comment: ok @WhatTheHeckTech i will check

Comment: @WhatTheHeckTech where did you add the layer.borderWidth code?

Comment: add this lines in your viewController implementation `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
  self.googleMapsView.frame = self.MapViewContainer.bounds
 }` and remove this line in `viewDidLoad` `self.googleMapsView.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: @WhatTheHeckTech let me know if my last comment solve your issue

Comment: @ReinierMelian It worked! Dude thank you so much! You don't know how long I have been trying to figure this out.

Comment: @ReinierMelian ok

Comment: added as answer @WhatTheHeckTech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of your ViewController, as I said in my comment and

```
func viewDidLayoutSubviews() { 
  super.viewDidLayoutSubviews() 
  self.googleMapsView.frame = self.MapViewContainer.bounds 
}
```

You also need to remove this line `self.googleMapsView.clipsToBounds = true` in `viewDidLoad`